# Segmentation fault: 11 when using calling 'ls'

Tags: c, shell, unix

Here I have created my method to simulate the 'ls' UNIX command in my UNIX shell implementation in C. 9/10 times my shell will work perfectly and the other time I get a segmentation fault: 11 on the 'ls' command. I am wondering what causes this fault to happen.

```
void lookInsideCurrentDirectory(char **parsed){
char** argv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);

int counter = 0;
while(parsed[counter] != NULL){
    argv[counter] = parsed[counter];
    printf("counter: %d argv: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);
    counter++;
}
argv[counter] = NULL;

pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == -1){
    return;
}
else if(pid == 0){
    if(execvp(argv[0], argv) == -1){
        perror("Error: ");
    }
    exit(0);
}
else{
    printf("child\n");
    wait(NULL); 
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: what is external context, call of function? what is `parsed`? BTW many subtle problem (risk) exists, it is far to be "percectly"

Comment: Please provide a more complete example of your program (i.e. a caller of lookInsideCurrentDirectory function).

Comment: On a side note, what is the reason for you shallow copying (I hope you know you're not copying the strings themselves) the parsed array? It seems that you could've just as easily passed it directly to `execvp(parsed[0], parsed)`.

Comment: Run it in a debugger, and see which line segfaults.

Comment: Would you perhaps be sending 100 or more elements in the `parsed` array to this code?  That'll blow up real good.